# Karma: Cannot find module in relative path

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, karma-runner, browserify

I have a hard time with Karma not being to load a specific file. I am a beginner regarding Karma, I however spend the entire day diving into the documentation and looking for similar issues without success.

When starting the karma process, it will fail when loading a config file. Here is the error:

```
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './development'
at /tmp/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:0 <- /tmp/7b47eeb55cec3f8cc510b5cd637c570a.browserify:1
```

I do not suspect the file to be the issue itself. My guess would be that the issue is around the 'require' action. This file is probably the first one to be 'required' during the execution. So Browserify could also be guilty.

files tree:

```
.
├── karma.conf.js
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── config
    │   ├── base.js
    │   ├── development.js
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── production.js
    ├── controllers
    │   ├── authentication.js
    │   └── __test__
    │       └── authentication.test.js
    ├── modules
    │   └── auth
    │       ├── builder.js
    │       └── __test__
    │           └── mocks
    │               └── builder.mock.js
    ├── router.js
    └── server.js
```

karma.conf.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(config) {

  config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'sinon-chai', 'browserify'],
    files: [
      'src/**/*.test.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.test.js': ['browserify']
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'mocha'],
    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: [
        ['babelify',{
          presets: ['es2015'],
        }]
      ]
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Fails in src/config/index.js

```
'use strict';

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('./' + env);

module.exports = config;
```

In order to give you guys a way to reproduce it, i built a small node application:
    https://github.com/slecorvaisier/karma-starterkit

Start with:

```
 npm run test
```

Versions: node-v: v6.2.0 npm -v: 3.8.9

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from your usage of require with variables, which is not supported in browserify.

Instead of writing :

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('./' + env);
```

try :

```
const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? require('./production') : require('./development');
```

The rule is that you can't use anything variable inside require.

Also see [Why can I not use a variable as parameter in the require() function of node.js (browserify)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051921/why-can-i-not-use-a-variable-as-parameter-in-the-require-function-of-node-js)

Comment: I solved my issue and posted my own answer 46 secs after yours so I didn't see it. But as you nailed it, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

as Browserify does not execute the code itself, the 'env' value will never be replaced.
See: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/377

The workaround for me is to modify the config file as the following (src/config/index.js) :
    'use strict';

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
let config = require('./development');

if (env === 'production') config = require('./production');

module.exports = config;
```

Which is not the best solution as I have to 'list' all the env, but the tests are now working properly. A definitive fix for me is to switch on webpack to handle this case more properly.