# Javascript: How to init Audio file with variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to play an audio file which will be set using a variable. I can set the path just fine when hardcoding the string - but not when using the variable.

```
    var path = "../../recordings/test.mp3"
    this.audio = new Audio(require('../../recordings/test.mp3')) // <- This line is fine
    this.audio = new Audio(require(path)) // <- This line gives the following error:
```

When using a `path` string I receive the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module '../../recordings/test.mp3'
> at webpackEmptyContext (components sync:2)
> at VueComponent.playAudio (MyCarousel.vue:119)
> at click (MyCarousel.vue?a868:120)

Why is it that I can file the file when explicitly hardcoding the string but not when using a variable for its path?

Comment: Why are you trying to `require()` the audio file? You just want `new Audio('../../recordings/test.mp3')`.

Comment: It doesn't work at all without the require

Comment: This helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051921/why-can-i-not-use-a-variable-as-parameter-in-the-require-function-of-node-js